# How to translate char * string = "2001-02-03" to integer format?

Tags: c++, integer, type-conversion

I have these strings:

```
const char * date = "2001-02-03";
const char * id = "987654/3210";
```

I need very fast translate to integer or maybe long integer ( for id). I need to translate for compare ( for numbers strcmp() is slowly ). I have only this library:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
```

Example: 
const char * date = "2001-02-03"; -> int int_date = 20010203; 
const char * id = "987654/3210"; -> long long_id = 9876543210;

How to do?

Comment: hint: conversion to int + int comparison (negligible) is unlikely to be faster than string comparison. you will only benefit from the conversion, if the comparison is made **multiple times**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the string, just `strcmp` is faster than converting(parsing) it to another format and then compare it.

But a simple way to parse it is :

```
const char * date = "2001-02-03";
int y, m, d;
int result = sscanf(date, "%d-%d-%d", &y, &m, &d);

if (result == 3)
{
    // use them
}
```

*(I suggest my code just as a sample)*